# BigQuery Table too large for JOIN & Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried two different ways to do this query, but I receive Table too large for join for the first one and Resources exceeded during query execution in the second one...

These queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(s_pageview_id)) as total
FROM impressions.tbl_impressions_201405
WHERE i_browser IN (1)
AND fk_i_id_tbl_vertical IN (1)
AND i_section IN (1)
AND s_ads_list != ''
AND b_is_human = true
AND DATE(dt_date) = '2014-05-28'
AND s_pageview_id NOT IN (
  SELECT s_pageview_id
  FROM impressions.tbl_impressions_201405
  WHERE i_section IN (26,27,83,96)
  AND i_browser IN (1)
  AND fk_i_id_tbl_vertical IN (1)
  AND DATE(dt_date) = '2014-05-28'
  AND s_ads_list != ''
  AND b_is_human = true
)
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM impressions.tbl_impressions_201405 as impressions_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH impressions.tbl_impressions_201405 as impressions_2
ON impressions_1.s_pageview_id = impressions_2.s_pageview_id
WHERE impressions_2.i_browser IN (1)
AND impressions_2.fk_i_id_tbl_vertical IN (1)
AND impressions_2.i_section IN (1)
AND impressions_2.b_is_human = true
AND DATE(impressions_2.dt_date) = '2014-05-28'
AND impressions_1.i_section IN (26,27,83,96)
```

Do you know any other way to try it?!

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is severely short on metadata.  How big are your tables, where is the join in the first one etc.  But:

1)  Try `JOIN EACH`.  You can be a bit more specific with joins, using [this visualisation as a guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg).
2)  Try saving the table and allowing for large results.
[image]